# fail face recognition model with ICA method

Tags: python, machine-learning, face-recognition

As part of my school project, I need to make a face recognition predictive model with my face date set.
i use FastICA (as part of assignment using ICA is mandatory) for dimension reduction and for classification I am using SVM (not mandatory).

My train set dimension (965,23296)

And my test set is (234,23296)

follow is part of my code.

```
n_components = 800
ica = FastICA(n_components=n_components, whiten=True).fit(train_set_x)

X_train_ica = ica.transform(train_set_x)
X_test_ica = ica.transform(test_set_x)

clf=SVC(kernel='linear',C=0.1)
clf.fit(X_train_ica, train_set_y)

Y_pred = clf.predict(X_test_ica)
```

The problem is that, when I run the code, classifier “clf” return only single value “Male_III” for whole Y_pred.

I already test the dataset and classifier with PCA algorithm and pretty sure that there is no issue with data set. the only thing that i have doubt is with fastICA configuration.

I would appreciate to help me with solution or some link.

Thank you so much